# Why does Ajax post data to localhost rather than the provided URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am using Ajax to post a form to a server, however, instead of sending the form to the URL, it sends to itself.

Here is the code

```
$("#psignup").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "example/default/mobile_user_register",
           data: $("#patientsignup").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

In the browser, it appears to send the from to `http://localhost:8080/?email=asdfa%40asd.com&password=asd&repeatpassword=&firstname=asd&username=&lastname=asd`

What I am looking for is, of course, "http://example.com/default/mobile_user_register?xxxxxxxxxxxxxx". Can you help me to understand why this isn't working?

Comment: Then put the full URL in your code, including the "http://" part.

Comment: I did, but it is not working.

Comment: Search ajax cross domain on google

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/default/mobile_user_register?xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    dataType: 'jsonp', //use jsonp data type in order to perform cross-domain ajax 
    crossDomain: true, 
    data: data, 
    success: callback,
    error: callback
});
```

Comment: JSONP is a good idea, but it won't work right away if the data he wants to post is too large (since it can't actually POST with JSONP, only GET).

Comment: @ColinDeClue You right but i just suggested him a way which might can suit requirement.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to point it out so he'd know about the limitation before hand. If it doesn't affect him, then this is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use javascript AJAX to post to another URL --> it is prevented by most browsers.

Comment: More on this topic: Same Origin Policy

Comment: So is there another way to post forms to the server and get response?

Comment: You can post a form to another server, but not through Ajax. You can post to your own domain (if you have that power) and then use something like CURL to send it along to another server.

Comment: @Collin Actually, I am posting it to my own doamain, but the server is written in web2py. So the index.html is in www.domain.com/application/views/default/ where the controller (mobile_user_register) is called by www.domain.com/application/default/mobile_user_login. Is there a way to redirect it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and the domain where this code is hosted is example.com but you're trying to call example.net, then AJAX security explicitly prohibits this.

What you'll need to do is to set up a tiny cgi proxy on your server that takes the call you want to make, and fetches that data and brings it back to you.

Assuming you were using PHP, your call will look like `myProxy.php?destination=http://example.net/whatever`

The proxy would then go fetch what it found at that destination and deliver it back in the response.

Comment: That's not the only option (it's a good one though). There's JSONP and CORS, as well.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. However, the server code was written in web2py, and I have no knowledge of that at all. How can I do it?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel sorry I forgot to tag you. Thanks

Answer (score -6):

It does not magically know that `example/default/mobile_user_register` is your domain name. Try http://example.com/default/mobile_user_register.